# jquery-ajax: pass values from a textfield to php file and show the value

Tags: php, html, jquery

## index.html

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


        <input type="text" id="inputtext"><input type="button" value="submit "id="submit">
                <br>                
        <div id="response">
        </div>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="thescript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## thescript.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){

        var dataString = $("#inputtext").val();



           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "greet.php",
             data: dataString,
             success: function(){
                 $("#response").load("greet.php");
              }
           });   


    });




});
```

## greet.php

```
<?PHP

print "hello " . $_POST['dataString'];

?>
```

The value that was entered in the textfield should show when the greet.php is loaded. not sure why it won't work

Comment: You don't seem to have the correct code for `index.html`.

Comment: You've pasted the javascript in twice - missing the HTML part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can easier:

```
$("#submit").click(function()
{
    var dataString = $("#inputtext").val();

           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "greet.php",
             data: "dataString=" + dataString,
             success: function(result){
                 $("#response").html(result);
              }
           });   
    });
```

And for php:

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST["dataString"]))
{
    echo "hello " . $_POST['dataString'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax returns the "hello" already. however while your page receives it, it queries "greet.php" again.

```
 $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "greet.php",
             data: dataString,
             success: function (response) {
                 $("#response").append(response); // or .html(response)
              }
           });
```

or better: use .post();

```
$.post("greet.php", dataString, function (response) {
    $("#response").append(response); // or .html(response)
});
```

finally, is your submit button is in a form, and you handle the click event, you shoudld prevent the form to submit on click if you want to stay on the page and not reload it.

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // stuff
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you've got your jQuery `.ajax` call right.  From the jQuery documentation:

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

You want to be passing params as your data, in key/value format, rather than just the data,  That way you can access it in your php as 'dataString' is to pass `data: "dataString=" + dataString` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){

        var dataString = $("#inputtext").val();

                 $("#response").load("greet.php"+ dataString );
              });   


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$("#response").load("greet.php", {dataString : dataString});
```