# jquery-ajax: pass values from a textfield to a php variable (same a file)

Tags: php, html, jquery

[jquery-ajax: pass values from a textfield to php file and show the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496686/jquery-ajax-pass-values-from-a-textfield-to-php-file-and-show-the-value)

i made a variation of the link above this time using only one file and no div tag.

## test.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){

    var dataString = $("#inputtext").val();

     $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "test.php",
             data: "dataString=" + dataString,
             success: function(result){
                 window.location.reload(true);
              }
          });   
  

    window.location.reload(true);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="inputtext">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="send">



<?PHP

if(isset($_POST['dataString'])){

$searchquery = trim($_POST['dataString']);

print "Hello " . $searchquery;

}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

value from dataString won't show. why?

Comment: `window.location.reload(true);` is similar to refreshing the page. That may be the case

Comment: Seems there're so many mistakes. You are submitting to the same page (`test.php`); and your AJAX call also goes to the same page (`test.php`); and you're reloading the same page (`test.php`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the question, but what's the point of using ajax to reload the same page?? Use it to call another page and then load the result, not the way you're doing it.
Try this

In test.php:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

    var dataString = $("#inputtext").val();

     $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "anothepage.php",
             data: dataString,
             success: function(result){
                 $('#result').html(result).
              }
          });   
     return false; //so the browser doesn't actually reload the page
  });
```

And you should actually use a form, not just inputs. And use the name attribute for them, or php won't pick the value! ID is for javascript and css.

```
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" id="inputtext" value="" name="inputtext">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="send" name="submit">
    </form>

<div id="result"> <!-- result from ajax call will be written here --> </div>
```

In anotherpage.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['inputtext'])){

$searchquery = trim($_POST['inputtext']);

echo htmlentities($searchquery); // We don't want people to write malicious scripts here and have them printed and run on the page, wouldn't we? 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you refresh the page using JavaScript, you lose any POST parameters you sent to the page. That is one reason why you never saw any valid results.

You are also missing the benefits from using AJAX - A motivating reason to deploy AJAX is to remove the requirement to refresh the page while still accepting and processing user input.

If you prefer to process the data from AJAX on the same page that is serving the HTML, here is a working example based on your supplied code.

```
<?php 
if( isset($_POST['dataString']))
{
    echo 'Hello ' . trim( $_POST['dataString']);
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Testing jQuery AJAX</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                var dataString = $("#inputtext").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: "dataString=" + dataString,
                    success: function( data){
                        alert( data);
                    }
                });   
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="inputtext" />
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="send" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```